# How do I install Ubuntu on /dev/sda and not /dev/sdb?

Tags: installation, partitioning

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7. The installer will only let me try to install on `/dev/sdb` which is my 32GB caching SSD. I have partitioned space for Ubuntu with Gparted.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: It wants to install the bootloader to `sdb`. I am not sure about this, but maybe `sda` is not in the format to install grub? I do not see why it would not install into `sda5` either.

Answer (score 2):

If the disk has been used in a RAID array you might need to erase the metadata. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
```

See http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12026527&postcount=2

You might also find that you need to create a partition table in GParted (Device > Create Partition Table) before the disk will be available in the Installer.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

don't do the guided partition scheme, do it manually.

if you want even more control, download the alternate install disk

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

but if you've never done it before, i wouldn't suggest doing it unless you have another computer or source of internet to answer questions and get help along the way

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) out. If you have a preexisting Windows install, I believe you don't want grub on /dev/sda because the windows bootloader is already there and that's best left as is.